# How to add a dll config file to a project that add the dll as reference?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, deployment, app-config

I wrote a UserLogin dll. 
The dll is using App.Config file with some default parameters. I have renamed the config file to UserLogin.Config for better files system readability.

I wrote a new application requiring login of users. I added the UserLogin.dll as reference to the new application. The problem is that the config file was not added with the reference. I have to add it manually to the bin\debug folder to be able to run the application through Visual Studio.

I do not have a such problem for deploying it since I am adding the config file as part of the setup.

What is the correct way to add the config file to the new application so I can run it in development environment?

Following is the UserLogin.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="IsTestEnvironment" value="false" />
        <add key="AllowedUserForTestEnvironment" value="ehh" />
        <add key="EnableLogging" value="false" />
     </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The class that reads from the UserLogin.config file:

```
public static class ConfigurationReader
{
    private static AppSettingsSection _appSettings;

    public static AppSettingsSection AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appSettings == null)
            {
                var userPreferencesConfigFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                userPreferencesConfigFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "UserLogin.config";
                var userPreferencesConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(userPreferencesConfigFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                _appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)userPreferencesConfig.GetSection("appSettings");                                        
            }

            return _appSettings;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsTestEnvironment
    {
        get
        {
            return bool.Parse(AppSettings.Settings["IsTestEnvironment"].Value);
        }
    }

    public static string AllowedUserForTestEnvironment
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.Settings["AllowedUserForTestEnvironment"].Value;
        }
    }

    public static string EnableLogging
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.Settings["EnableLogging"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The new Application that use the UserLogin.dll:

[image]

Comment: Settings have limitations, they are only valid for an EXE.  Which makes sense if you think about it, a library can be used in multiple programs and would have different settings.  Technically it is possible, you would have to merge the app.config entries by hand into the app.config for the EXE project.  Not a lot of fun.  A correct way to do it is to let a library be configured by code in the EXE.  Or just use an .xml file that you load yourself from a well-known location.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have renamed the config file name to a custom name.

Ideally any DLL can use configuration from the parents Exes App.config, and you only need to add your appsettings to the App.config file of the application(exe) which is using the dll.

Why did you separate it this way. This is not a good practice.

Now since you separated it, it is much like same as having a custom xml configuration file.

In such case you can try to add Post-Build or Pre-Build command using XCOPY to copy the config file to the right output directory so that DLL picks it up.

Right click project properties, go to Pre-Build event, add a command like

xcopy /y "$(SolutionDir)MyProject\myFile.xxx" "$(OutputDir)"

Note you may need to change the Path and file name to suit your need.

Comment: if I understood you right, you are saying that it is better to write everything to the App.Config of the dll. And for each application that will use this dll, I will have to copy the AppSettings part to the Application AppConfig file, right?

Comment: Yes you got it right. Just do away with the custom file, and the app settings in exes app.config, after that the normal configuration API would work as usual